# Postgres Trigger for Timestamp in related table

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I want to use a trigger to auto-update a table's updated_at date, but the problem is that the actual "update" happens in a separate table. I'll water-down the tables to make it more clear:

```sql
-- Trigger
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_set_timestamp()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  NEW.updated_at = NOW();
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Table to update
CREATE TABLE bug (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
);

CREATE TRIGGER set_timestamp
BEFORE UPDATE ON bug
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_set_timestamp();
```

Fairly standard, but there's no column to actually update. The real "update" is coming from a comment thread table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE comment_thread (
  bug_id INTEGER REFERENCES bug(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  comment VARCHAR(2000),
  PRIMARY KEY (bug_id, user_id)
);
```

So my question is if there's a way to use that trigger (or some variation of) to update the `updated_at` field in the related row when creating a comment?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Put the trigger on the `comment_thread` table and use `now()` there in an `UPDATE` query that sets `updated_at` in `bug` using the `bug_id = id` relationship.

Comment: To see a generic audit trigger that is doing the same general thing see: Example 42.4. A PL/pgSQL Trigger Function for Auditing at [Trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER)

Comment: So I attached the trigger to the `comment_thread` table, and added this line to the trigger function `UPDATE bug SET updated_at = NOW() WHERE id = NEW.bug_id` since the NEW can grab any field being inserted from the table it's triggered from. Seems to work, thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Glad it worked.